# What is the default doc sequence of the result from an Elasticsearch filter request?

Tags: sql, database, search, elasticsearch, lucene

I recently run an Elasticsearch filter request that is

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "terms" : {
              "a_id" : [ 257793, 257798, 257844 ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "explain" : false,
  "fields" : "a_id"
}
```

So that I can find all docs with `a_id` in `257793, 257798, 257844` and the results are `257844, 257798, 257793`. So far so good.

Then I find that whatever the sequence of the term numbers are, the return docs are always in the same `a_id` order. That is, even I run

```
     "terms" : {
          "a_id" : [257798, 257844, 257793 ]
        }
```

The result docs are in the order of `257844, 257798, 257793` as well.

So I am so curious about the mechanism behind the Elasticsearch filtering. Can anyone help me and give me a hint?

Comment: I think it might be relevant with the "index sequence" stored in ES but there is no "mature theory" in my mind to prove that.

Comment: Also `a_id` is kinds of "unique_id" that there is no 2 docs has the same `a_id`. So the inverted index it is like `257798 -> doc_257798`, `257844 -> doc_257844`

Answer (score 0):

By default, ES returns in descending order of _score. You can provide the sort option, to say in which order and based on what you want the results to be returned. For e.g., for based on date field

```
{
    "sort": { "date": { "order": "desc" }}
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

You can get more information:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but by default ES does not return in descending order, since I have tried, But with a middle value as the first. : (

Comment: I had missed to explain correctly in my answer. `In Elasticsearch, the relevance score is represented by the floating-point number returned in the search results as the _score, so the default sort order is _score descending.` So the default is the desc order, but not with `_id` value, but the `_score`. You can try with `"sort": { "a_id": {"order": "desc"}}`